# Material design: Can you use bottom and top app bar at the same time? What's the relation between them?

Tags: mobile, buttons, android, layout, material-design

I'm currently designing a B2B app that will have plenty of buttons (on top app bar) that just can't be hidden. Is it possible to transfer some of the buttons from top app bar to bottom app bar, just like this?

[image]

Comment: The Material guidelines literally contain a paragraph just about that (under **Pairing with a top app bar**): https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#behavior

Answer (score 3):

Material Design is a design system for making design systems, paired with a set of *guidelines*. They are not rules. You've used many Material Design apps without realizing it, I'm sure.

Material's [App Bar: Bottom](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#anatomy) appears to illustrates many of the layout concerns you have.

[image]

The [Behavior](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#behavior) section has recommendations on how to pair a bottom and top app bar together.